# Continuity of maps between metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I want to determine for the following maps $A\rightarrow B$, for which points of $A$ the map is continuous:

> 1. $(\mathbb{C},d_E)\rightarrow(\mathbb{C},d_E)$,
>      $z\mapsto \left\{
>         \begin{array}{lr}
>           (\exp(z)-1)/z & : z\neq 0\\
>           0 & : z=0
>         \end{array}
>       \right.$
> 2. $(\mathbb{R},d_E)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},d_F)$, $x\mapsto x$
> 3. $(\mathbb{R},d_E)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},d_E)$, $
>       x\mapsto \left\{
>         \begin{array}{lr}
>           x & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
>           -x & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
>         \end{array}
>       \right.
>    $
> 4. $(\mathbb{R},d_F)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},d_E)$, $
>       x\mapsto \left\{
>         \begin{array}{lr}
>           x & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
>           -x & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
>         \end{array}
>       \right.
>    $

Here $d_E(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_F(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}0&:x=y\\|x|+|y|&: x\neq y\end{array}\right.$.

**What I have done:**
I know that continuity of $f$ means that for all $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $d_X(x,y)<\delta\implies d_Y(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$. The problem is that for the cases above I don't know for which subsets of $A$ the maps are continuous.

1. For $z,w\neq 0$, we must find a $\delta$ such that $|z-w|<\delta\implies|(\exp(z)-1)/z-(\exp(w)-1)/w|<\epsilon$. Can we find one? And what do I do with $0$?
2. Here $|x-y|<\delta\implies|x|+|y|<\epsilon$. Again, for which $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and which $\delta$ does this hold?
3. Clearly this holds for all points in $\mathbb{Q}$ if we take $\delta=\epsilon$. But what about those that aren't in $\mathbb{Q}$?
4. Here we need $|x|+|y|<\delta\implies|x-y|<\epsilon$ for points in $\mathbb{Q}$. Which delta can we take? And same question as in 3.

Comment: as to 1: I think you can assume that $\exp(z)$ and $\frac{1}{z}$ etc are continuous on the complex numbers in the usual metric. Only $0$ is the issue. What is the limit as $z \rightarrow 0$ of the expression?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma 0, right?

Comment: Indeed, and this would show that the function is continuous at $0$ as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So the map of 1 is continuous for all $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you're allowed to use all I said.

Comment: Actually, in number 1 I believe the limit as $z \to 0$ is $1$.

Comment: @LotharNarins You are right